# HTML file browse not working in iPad

Tags: ipad, html

The HTML file browse element isn’t working in iPad.

Example:

```
<input type="file" />
```

The choose file button always remains disabled.

Comment: what do you mean by not working, and what is your question?

Comment: Remember, applications are sandboxed.

Comment: Why is this HTML5 specific? last I checked input type file has been around a while.

Answer (score 7):

You can’t upload files from an iPad in that way; iPad apps can’t browse the filesystem.

Comment: iOS 6 Safari will support uploading photos and videos, though.

Answer (score 6):

That's true. Safari Mobile doesn't support file transfer over HTTP.

Comment: Does any other mobile browser support that feature?

Comment: I think Opera Mini does, but I don't think there's any way to do that on an iPad.

Comment: iOS 6 Safari will support uploading photos and videos, though.

Comment: @user482594: Yes. Android ICS / Chrome supports it.

Comment: In the mean time, there are solutions indeed. (And about time!)