# iPhone & Android: how to take a picture and upload it to a website?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, asp.net

I'm building an asp.net website using c# and .net 2.0. One of the pages requires to take a picture (or choose from already existing pictures), upload it to the server, add other info and save everything in the database.

I'm using a FileUpload control and everything is working fine on a PC.

Android gives me the options to choose a file from Gallery, File system, Music Track etc. but there is no option to take a picture from the camera.
The FileUpload control is disabled in iPhone.

I want to click on a button or use something else and be able to choose to upload an image from the gallery or start the camera and take one. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML file browse not working in iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463818/html-file-browse-not-working-in-ipad)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. native HTML5 doesn't support camera integration (yet)

Comment: @Shai: It's not an HTML 5 issue, really. Safari just doesn't support file inputs prior to iOS 6.

Comment: Yeah, but it is possible to use the camera using HTML5, and, lets say, PhoneGap... I was referring to the camera issue (-:

Comment: @Shai: Again, this works fine on Android. I suspect it will work on iOS 6, as well. It's a limitation of Mobile Safari, nothing more. Also, rampage: Android 4 ICS allows you to take a picture with the camera.

Answer (score -1):

Allowing the user to choose a picture from the gallery or take a new picture (if the device supports photography) both exist within the same class. That class is named [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and has a property named 'sourceType' that allows you to designate whether the user will be taking a photo, choosing from the gallery, etc.

-edit-

This is for iOS

Comment: Can you please give me some idea on how to implement this is my asp.net web site?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to build a native app

Comment: Are there any free already built solutions that I can use since I have absolutely no idea of Objective C coding.

Are there any other solutions because I think that not everyone would want to install an app to use this feature (I have hardly any experience with iStuff).

Comment: I found this link in another question, I think it addresses your need: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/

Comment: I will delete this answer because I know it is not what you are looking for. I compiled a better another better answer that I think addresses your need.