# <t:inputFileUpload> not work in ipad

Tags: ipad, jsf, file-upload

i use JSF `<t:inputFileUpload>` tag to upload files to my site. It works properly in a PC with all browsers but when I test it in my `iPad` it does not work.  It shows as disabled in `iOS 5`. It uploads images but not text files or pdf or word or excel files  in `iOS 6`.

Have you faced a similar situation? How can I upload documents and spreadsheets from an iPad onto my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not specific to JSF. It's basically just a HTML code generator. It runs on webserver and produces a bunch of HTML which get sent to the client (in your case, the iPad) and then interpreted over there. The `<t:inputFileUpload>` just generates a HTML `<input type="file">`.

That HTML element is in turn indeed disabled in Safari Mobile based browsers. JSF look like a magician, but it really can't control whatever the client decides to do with the retrieved HTML. You'd need to look for a 3rd party client side library which enables this in the Safari Mobile side.

#### See also:

- [A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app)
- [upload files via iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081997/upload-files-via-ipad)
- [HTML file browse not working in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463818/html-file-browse-not-working-in-ipad)