# Upload Disabled - When accessing website on mobile

Tags: jsf, web-applications, file-upload, jsf-2, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<t:inputFileUpload> not work in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712400/tinputfileupload-not-work-in-ipad)

application using JSF 2.0. I have file upload option and I have used tomahawk for the same.

```
<t:inputFileUpload />
```

where `t` is `xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"`.

When I browse the site through mobile, I am not able to upload. I see option as `Upload Disabled`.

Can anyone tell me what is this error and how to resolve this issue?

I have seen this problem on below mobiles.

```
iPhone 4s (Safari default browser)
Sony Ericson Xperia X10 Mini Pro (Android Default browser)
```

---

### Edit 1

Same things happen for yahoo and gmail also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not `t:inputFileUpload` related , but Browser...

Download *opera mini* from the market...

Comment: and the problem will be solved?

Comment: that means for Upload option, it will support only on OPERA?

Comment: seems that way http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/531708-photo-upload-disabled-all-website-my-samsung-please-help.html

Comment: could you please take a look at my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999353/images-wont-load-if-they-are-of-high-size)

Comment: @FahimParkar I saw that BalusC is on the case :)

Comment: thanks for looking into it...

Comment: finally God saved me. Just at answer.. Might help you sometime. This problem occurs especially when you have large size images